# How to use rac_signalForControlEvents

Tags: swift4, reactive-cocoa, reactive-swift

How can I convert same method "rap_signalForControlEvents" to last working ReactiveCocoa Version?

[image: Method example]

I'm trying to build a example of the  book Reactive programming with swift, but when I implemented the same method it doesn't work.

I've changed the reactiveCocoa version to the same of the book example but I think it's not updated for the new Swift Version.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately [images of code are not OK](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please [edit] your question and include your code as a plain, [formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) text. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how old the version you're using is, but at some point the library was split into two separate modules:

1. [**ReactiveSwift**](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveSwift) for the general reactive primitives and operators.
2. [**ReactiveCocoa**](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa) for reactive integration with Cocoa.

So first make sure you have both of those libraries in your project. Then you can create a control event signal like this:

```
cell.addButton.reactive.controlEvents(.touchUpInside)
    .observeValues { _ in
        // Handle the button press here
    }
```